# Truncate date by month with custom start day in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am getting some statistics using a query like

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', created_at) AS time, count(DISTINCT "user_id") AS mau 
FROM "session" 
GROUP BY time 
ORDER BY time;
```

Which is working fine if I want to get monthly active users for each calendar month. But I would like to shift the result to show last X moths starting from today instead of actual calendar months. How do I do? Can I add an offset in some way?

EDIT

As an example, I am currently getting results like

```
time       | mau
2022-04-01 | 10
2022-05-01 | 20
2022-06-01 | 30
```

But I would like it to be something like (where 2022-06-07 is today)

```
time       | mau
2022-04-07 | 10
2022-05-07 | 20
2022-06-07 | 30
```

Comment: can you share sample data and corresponding output? @rablentain

Comment: @lemon added an example

Comment: add some sample data

Comment: @rablentain thanks, I do appreciate that. Could you add also some sample *input* data from the table *"session"* that leads to have your current output?

Comment: What result would you like to see on the 31. July? There is no `2022-06-31` or `2022-02-31`.

Comment: So what is the period for counting. For example your first line of what you would like indicates a beginning date of `2022-04-07` but what in the ending date. Is it  `2022-04-30` (end of month) or `2022-05-06`.

Comment: So I think rather than months I would like each entry to be grouped by 30 day intervals

Comment: Then you should update the question to that effect **not** just add another comment.